# Multiplication of large numbers

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

While analyzing algorithms, I see that we usually assume multiplication to take single computer instruction. But this assumption is not apt when the size of the number (in terms of the number of bits). In the most basic form of multiplication, multiplying two n bit numbers usually is O(n^2). In context of this, what may be the complexity(in terms of bit operations) for calculating x^n.(x raised to the power of n) ?

With the explained approach, the complexity to me seems to be exponential in n (but not sure of the exact figure)

Comment: O(n2) seems nonsensical. Do you mean O(2 * n) or O(n^2)? Note the former is still O(n).

Comment: With the [right algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) multiplication can be brought down to slightly less than O(N x log N x log log N).

Comment: You want to take into account how the hardware actually multiplies?

Comment: Surely you'd use Exponentiation By Squaring to calculate `x^n`, rather than multiplying `x` by itself `n` times?

Comment: @phant0m but deriving a general limit wouldn't be possible with hardware implementation

Comment: @phant0m well actually I didn't consider it but if there's something that can be deduced, it would be really helpful to broaden my analysis

Comment: Check this for analysis of algorithm which one is best. [an algorithm to multiply of Large numbers](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/08/design-algorithm-to-multiply-of-large.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity of calculating `x^n` depends of course on the used algorithm for calculating the power, and multiplication. If you compute the power per Exponentiation by squaring, you need O(log n) multiplications. In each step, you either square one number, or you multiply two numbers and square one of the two.

If `x` has `d(x)` digits, the `x^n` has Θ(n*d(x)) digits, in the last step, you square a number of about `n/2*d(x)` digits (and possibly multiply that number with a smaller one) and the algorithm is then finished by multiplying the repeated square `x^(2^k)`, if `2^k <= n < 2^(k+1)`, with the accumulator.

Let `S(m)` be the cost of squaring an `m`-digit number (may or may not be the same as the cost `M(m)` of multiplying two arbitrary `m`-digit numbers). The squarings then need approximately

```
S(2^(k-1)*d(x)) + S(2^(k-2)*d(x)) + S(2^(k-3)*d(x)) + ...
```

work. Since `S(m) >= m`, that is between `S(2^(k-1)*d(x))` and `2*S(2^(k-1)*d(x))`. So the work for the squarings is dominated by the last step. For the multiplication of an `x^(2^s)` with the accumulator, the same holds, the final multiplication dominates the work. The final accumulator can be nearly as large as the repeated square, so the total cost of raising `x` to the `n`-th power by repeated squaring is

```
Θ(M(2^k*d(x)),
```

which is `Θ(M(n*d(x)))`. With the naive multiplication - `M(m) = O(m^2)` - you then get a total cost of `O(n^2*d(x)^2)`. Using a more advanced multiplication algorithm (Karatsuba, Toom-Cook, Schönhage-Strassen, ...), you get a much lower complexity, down to a little above `O(n*d(x)*log (n*d(x)) * log log (n*d(x)))`.

When computing the power iteratively by multiplying with `x`, in `n` steps, let `M(m,k)` denote the cost of multiplying an `m`-digit number with a `k`-digit number. Since one of the factors is always `x`, the total cost is

```
M(d(x),d(x)) + M(d(x),2*d(x)) + M(d(x),3*d(x)) + ... + M(d(x),(n-1)*d(x))
```

With the schoolbook algorithm with the cost `M(m,k) = m*k`, this sums up to `n*(n-1)/2*d(x)^2`, so the total cost is again `Θ(n^2*d(x)^2)`. But the constant factors are larger than for the exponentiation by repeated squaring.

When you are multiplying numbers of greatly differing lengths, as happens here after a few iterations, you cannot - as far as I know - reduce the cost `M(m,k)` much below `Θ(m*k)` - if `m < k`, view the numbers as a 1-digit number and an `r`-digit number (`r*m <= k < (r+1)*m`) in base `b^m`, you can reduce the cost of multiplying "digits" using the better algorithms if `m` is large enough, but you cannot reduce the `r` factor. So this algorithm then has a complexity of `O(n^2*M(d(x)))`, the factor of `n^2` cannot be eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) has a good overview of the complexity times for various multiplication algorithms.

To answer your question through, assuming the naive schoolbook method of multiplying two m-digit numbers (which has a complexity of O( m^2 ) and the naive method of raising to a power by multiplying a number by itself n times, you have n multiplications, so a complexity of O( n  * m^2 ) or simply O( nm^2 )

Comment: `m` is a length in digits of an input while `n` is the magnitude of an input, mixing them together like that gives a slightly misleading (confusing, at least) result in my opinion.

Comment: @harold can you please clarify in some more detail ?

Comment: @krammer well `m` is the *length* of `x`, but `n` is just `n` itself, and that sort of "hides" that the complexity depends on the length (which is typically used when discussing the complexity of things) of `n` in an exponential way.

Comment: @harold ok, if I got it correctly, so in my case, the complexity would be O(n^3) but its deceptive here.

Answer (score 1):

n^k costs :

```
O((log(n))^k)
```

log(n) - bit-representation of n

^k - because simple algorithm for multiplying two n-digits numbers costs O(n^2)